# Cookie Rewrite with NGINX

Tags: nginx, cookies, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Okay so I've set up a nginx server that proxies to another 2 servers with load balancing. The only thing now missing are the cookies.

I've been searching numerous forums and questions regarding the rewriting of cookies. Can anyone please give me insight as to how to fix this issue?

The web application deployed to the 2 servers are written with Vaadin. 
The 2 servers are running TomEE on port 8080 and 8081 for example.

I'm rewriting through nginx from easy.io to server1:8080 and server2:8080.

Refer to image below: when navigating to server1:8080/myapplication all my cookies are available.

https://ibb.co/X86pvCq

https://ibb.co/0M0GjCt

Refer to image below: when navigating to http://worksvdnui.io/ my cookies are not available.

https://ibb.co/qBkBRqb

I've tried using proxy_cookie_path, proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie but to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
upstream worksvdnuiio {
# ip_hash; sticky sessions!
ip_hash;
# server localhost:8080;

server hades:9090;
server loki:9090;
}

server {
listen      80;
listen      [::]:80;
server_name worksvdnui.io;

proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

location /PUSH {

    proxy_pass "http://worksvdnuiio/test.qa.gen/PUSH";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
    proxy_read_timeout 84600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 84600s;
    break;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass "http://worksvdnuiio/test.qa.gen/";
    proxy_cookie_path /test.qa.gen/ /;

    proxy_set_header            Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_pass_request_headers  on;
}

}
```

Any insight would be VALUABLE!

Thanks in advance.